# Question on the regular pentagon and triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

**CONTEXT**

I was recently working on some Euclidean geometry problems that involved regular pentagons and triangles, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295312/solve-the-angle-angledcb-in-triangle-triangleabc-with-anglea-84/4720670#4720670), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705518/p-is-a-point-in-triangle-abc-with-angle-pbc-angle-pcb-24-circ-angl/4706568#4706568) (to which the current question specifically refers). I noted that sometimes I was "forced" to introduce a "dummy" point that I then proved being coincident with the point actually involved in the hypotheses. My quesiton is, therefore, if this procedure is really needed, and, if so, "why".

**THE PROBLEM**

Here is the problem statement, that, as mentioned, is part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705518/p-is-a-point-in-triangle-abc-with-angle-pbc-angle-pcb-24-circ-angl/4706568#4706568) proof.

[image]

**Let $PQRST$ be a regular pentagon, and let $U$ be a point on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, such that $\measuredangle PQU = 42^\circ$. Prove that $\triangle RTU$ is equilateral.**

**MY APPROACH**

I solved the problem by introducing the equilateral triangle $\triangle RTU'$. Angle chasing and the fact that $\triangle TQU'$ is isosceles leads to the required result, that is $\measuredangle PQU' = 42^\circ$, and **therefore $U'\equiv U$**.

**MY QUESTION**

I would say I formally showed the reversed implication, i.e. that *if the triangle is equilateral than $\measuredangle PQU = 42^\circ$*. However, since there is only one point $U$  on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$ with the property $\measuredangle PQU = 42^\circ$, then we can also state that the original assertion is true.

Is there a more direct approach, not involving the point $U'$? If not, does it make any sense to ask oneself *why this is not possible*? And, if so, what is the answer to this question?

Comment: It is not needed. Another approach would be to use trigonometry to chase down the lengths,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \angle PQU$.

We want to show that $\alpha = \frac{7 \pi}{30} = 42°$.

The way I have obtained the result is by applying the sine law to triangle $RQU$. Here is how.

- $\angle URQ = \angle SRQ -(\angle SRT + \angle TRU)=\frac{3 \pi}{5}-\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{15}.$
- $\angle RQU =\frac{3 \pi}{5}+\alpha.$
- as a consequence (sum of angles = $\pi$) :

$$\angle QUR =\frac{\pi}{3}-\alpha \tag{0}$$

Please note that (0) implies that $\alpha \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{3}]$.

Besides,

- $RQ = 2 \sin \frac{\pi}{5}$ (pentagon's side),
- $UR = 2 \sin \frac{2\pi}{5}=4 \sin\frac{\pi}{5}\cos\frac{\pi}{5}$ (pentagon's diagonal)

We are now able to apply sine law in triangle $PQU$ :

$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{5}+\alpha\right)}{UR}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\alpha\right)}{RQ} \ \iff \ \frac{\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{5}+\alpha\right)}{4 \sin\frac{\pi}{5}\cos\frac{\pi}{5}}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\alpha\right)}{2 \sin\frac{\pi}{5}}$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{5}+\alpha\right)=2\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\alpha\right)\tag{1}$$

In the domain of possible variation $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{3}]$ for $\alpha$, the LHS of (1) is decreasing (negative derivative) whereas its RHS is increasing ; therefore if there is a solution $\alpha$ to (1) (and we know there is one !), it is unique.

It suffices to check that taking $\alpha=\frac{7\pi}{30}$ gives an identity in (1). A small calculation shows that it amounts to verify that :

$$\underbrace{\sin\frac{5\pi}{6}}_{= \ 1/2}=2 \ \underbrace{\cos\frac{\pi}{5}}_{\Phi/2}\underbrace{\sin\frac{\pi}{10}}_{\tfrac12 (\Phi-1)}$$

(using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137102/305862) and formula $\sin^2a=\frac12(1-\cos(2a))$, where $\Phi$ is the golden ratio), with an immediate verification (due to relationship $\Phi^2=\Phi+1$).

Comment: This solution is in the spirit of the comment by @Calvin Lin. Any comment from you ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. If I'm correct you assume that $RTU$ is equilateral. In that case it's probably easier if you observe that $TQU$ is isosceles and by angle chasing obtain $\measuredangle QTU=24^\circ$. Hence $\measuredangle TQU=78^\circ$, which quickly leads to $\measuredangle PQU =\measuredangle TQU - \measuredangle TQP = 42^\circ$. Your approach can easily be reversed, though (+1).

Comment: I was hoping more for a *synthetic solution* of the fact "if $\measuredangle PQU = 42^\circ$ then $RTU$ is equilateral. But I didn't mention that in OP.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that TQU is isosceles provides a good shortcut...

Comment: Yes. The point is that it seems I cannot reverse my approach, for some reason that I can't still grasp.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find a direct "synthetic" approach.

Recall that our hypothesis is that $PQRST$ is a regular pentagon, $U$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, with $\measuredangle PQU = 42^\circ$. We want to show that $\triangle RTU$ is equilateral.

Since $\triangle RTU$ is isosceles, we need to show that $\measuredangle RTU = 60^\circ$.

[image]

Construct the equilateral triangles $\triangle STW$ and $\triangle QUV$ as shown above.

1. Angle chasing shows that $\measuredangle WPQ = 42^\circ$ (so that $PW \parallel QU$) and $\measuredangle WQU = \measuredangle QUP = 96^\circ$. This means that $PUQW$ is an isosceles trapezoid, and, in particular $PU \cong QW$.
2. This, together with the fact that $\measuredangle VQW = \measuredangle VUP = 36^\circ$, yields $\triangle VQW \cong \triangle VUP$ (SAS).
3. Therefore, $\triangle PVW$ is isosceles.
4. $TPVW$ is a kite, and, thus $\measuredangle PTV = \measuredangle VTW = 24^\circ$.
5. Since by construction and angle chasing $\measuredangle TPV = 78^\circ$, we have (thanks to 4.) that $\triangle TPV$ is isosceles.
6. $TPUV$ is then also a kite, and $\measuredangle PTU = \measuredangle UTV = 12^\circ$.
7. Thus $\measuredangle RTU = 60^\circ$, and we reach our thesis.